# Accessing public variables from inside ccTouchesBegan method in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm having little trouble accessing public ivars form the ccTouchesBegan method,

I have this Scene:

```
class introScene : public cocos2d::CCLayer {
public:
    virtual bool init();
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
    bool autoScroll;

    virtual void ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
    void skip();

    CREATE_FUNC(introScene);
};
```

and from inside the .cpp file I try to access the variable **autoScroll**, but it insists that the variable doesn't exist, am I doing anything wrong here ??

```
void ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
        autoScroll = false;

}
```

This generates: **use of undeclared identifier 'autoScroll'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know *anything* about cocos2d, but I reckon you've defined the method incorrectly as you've missed off the class name.  Try this:

```
void introScene::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event){
    // ^^^^^^^
    autoScroll = false;
}
```

Comment: Awesome !!, that was it, I don't know how I even missed that ! :), cheers !